# Locus of a point N with the given constraints

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

> Through a point O$(0,0)$ , a line L is drawn which meets two other lines *$3x+4y=5$* and *$x+2y=3$* at points P and Q. 
>   Find the locus of N on the variable line if ON is the *arithmetic mean of OP AND OQ.*

**A try**

I used the parametric form of an arbitrary line and calculated the mean distance to be $$\frac{0.5(19 \cos x+25 \sin x)}{(3\cos ^2 x+10 \sin^2 x+ 11 \sin 2x)}$$ I was unable to use this to write the locus . I was looking for a hint or an alternate approach to the problem.

Comment: Hint: $N$ is the midpoint of $PQ$.

Comment: @Aretino Yeah , that's what I used to calculate the distance of that point as a function of x(the slope of the line),

Comment: You needn't calculate the distance. To find the locus, you must give the coordinates of $N$ as a function of some parameter.

Answer (score 2):

for both lines we get
$$y=-\frac{3}{4}x+\frac{5}{4}$$ and
$$y=-\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{3}{2}$$
for l we take $$y=mx$$ and we get the cordinates of both points $P,Q$ as
$$P\left(\frac{5}{3+4m};\frac{5m}{3+4m}\right)$$
$$Q\left(\frac{3}{1+2m};\frac{3m}{1+2m}\right)$$
Can you finish?
then $N$ has the coordinates
$$N\left(\frac{x_P+x_Q}{2};\frac{y_Q+y_P}{2}\right)$$
setting $$x=\left(\frac{5}{3+4m}+\frac{3}{1+2m}\right)\cdot \frac{1}{2}$$
after some algebra we obtain
$$m=\frac{9-10x-\sqrt{81+12x+4x^2}}{16x}$$
or
$$m=\frac{9-10x+\sqrt{81+12x+4x^2}}{16x}$$
can you now finish?

Comment: I am unable to eliminate n. I tried using m=(k/h)

Comment: Got it by using m=k/h

Comment: should i post you  the other two equations?

Comment: thanks . Got it.

Answer (score 1):

Say $y=lx$ is variable line through $(0,0)$. Then $$P\left({5\over 4l+3}, {5l\over 4l+3}\right)$$ and 
$$Q\left(\frac{3}{2l+1},\frac{3l}{2l+1}\right)$$
also  $y_N =lx_N$ and $$2x_N =  {5\over 4l+3} + {3\over 2l+1}={22l+14\over 8l^2+10l+3} $$

Rewrite $x \to x_N$ and $y\to y_N$. Then we have: $$2x =  {22lx^2+14x^2\over 8l^2x^2+10lx^2+3x^2} = {22yx+14x^2\over 8y^2+10yx+3x^2}$$ and we get the hyperbola:$$8y^2+10xy+3x^2 = 11y+7x$$

Comment: There should be a three instead of a one in 8l^2+10l+..

Answer (score 0):

For any line $\ell : ax + by = c$ in the plane, $n = (a,b)$ is a normal vector for that line. In terms of $n$, we can rewrite the condition that a point $p = (x,y)$ lying on line $\ell$ as $n \cdot p = c$.

Let's say we have two lines $\ell_1, \ell_2$ which are disjoint from $O = (0,0)$.
If we draw a line $\ell_3$ through $O$ along some direction $d$ and let it hit
line $\ell_1$ at $p_1 = \lambda_1 d$ and hit the line $\ell_2$ at $p_2 = \lambda_2 d$. We will have
$$
\begin{cases}
n_1 \cdot p_1 = \lambda_1 n_1 \cdot d = c_1\\
n_2 \cdot p_2 = \lambda_2 n_2 \cdot d = c_2
\end{cases}
\quad\implies\quad 
\begin{cases}
\lambda_1 = \frac{c_1}{n_1\cdot d}\\
\lambda_2 = \frac{c_2}{n_2\cdot d}
\end{cases}
$$
Let $p_3$ be the mid-point of $p_1, p_2$, we have
$$p_3 = \frac12(p_1+p_2) = \frac12(\lambda_1+\lambda_2) d
= \frac12\left(\frac{c_1}{n_1\cdot d}+ \frac{c_2}{n_2\cdot d}\right) d
= \frac12\left(\frac{c_1}{n_1\cdot p_3}+ \frac{c_2}{n_2\cdot p_3}\right)p_3$$
This leads to

$$\frac12\left(\frac{c_1}{n_1\cdot p_3}+ \frac{c_2}{n_2\cdot p_3}\right) = 1
\quad\iff\quad
\left(n_1 \cdot p_3 - \frac{c_1}{2}\right)\left(n_2 \cdot p_3 - \frac{c_2}{2}\right)
= \frac{c_1c_2}{4}$$

For the problem at hand, we can set $\ell_1$ to the line $3x + 4y = 5$ and $\ell_2$ to the line $x+2y = 3$. i.e.
$$n_1 = (3,4), c_1 = 5\quad\text{ and }\quad n_2 = (1,2), c_2 = 3$$
$P, Q, N$ will take the roles of $p_1, p_2, p_3$ in above discussion.
As a result, $N = (x,y)$ satisfy:
$$
\left(3x+4y - \frac{5}{2}\right)\left(x + 2y - \frac{3}{2}\right) = \frac{15}{2}
\quad\iff\quad
3x^2 + 10xy + 8y^2 -7x-11y = 0
$$
This is the equation of a hyperbola  having lines $\tilde{\ell}_1 : 3x+4y = 
\frac{5}{2}$ and $\tilde{\ell}_2 : x + 2y - \frac{3}{2}$ as asymptotes.
Geometrically, $\tilde{\ell}_1$ is a line parallel to $\ell_1$ and mid way between $O$ and $\ell_1$. Same thing happens to asymptote $\tilde{\ell}_2$.

One branch of this hyperbola passes through $O$. The other branch passes through $X$, the intersection of $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$.
The pair of lines $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ divides the plane into $4$ components.
When $O$ lies between $P, Q$, $N$ falls on the branch passes through $O$. This branch is contained in the interior of that component containing $O$.
Otherwise, $N$ falls on the branch passes through $X$. With the exception of $X$, this branch is contained in the union of interior of the two components adjacent to the one containing $O$.